# GPU OOM when training ResNet but there are GPUs spare still

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

The resnet34 I am training with batch szie 256 would cause OOM. But the machine I am using has 8 Titan GPUs with 12G GPU memory respectively,  I noticed that there are still 7 GPU spare when OOM happen.

I am wondering why would this happen. Can't tensorflow uses other parallel GPUs when the first GPU is ran out of memory? How to solve this?

……………………………………update…………………………………
actually I did set all gpus  workable by coding   "os.environment"， what else did I miss or is there anything wrong?

Comment: You need to explicitly write tf GPU code to do that, it won't directly.

Answer (score 0):

1.
It hanpped because batchsize=256 is too huge to load in GPU with 12G (14G may be suffecicient in this case).

The only way is to decrease the batch_number.

2. --Why can'ttensorflow use memory of paralle GPUs to solve this?
   --I don't find any clue that tensorflow supports it. And I have try to use "with tf.device()" to set different Variables to different GPUs, but it don't help. Because no matter how I distribute them, Once the data are load, the first layer taking the data would make GPU where this variable exists OOM.
3. finally my solution is to cut 256 to 128.
4. PS: In this period, I have try to set `sess.run([train_imges, train_labels])` run in CPU. But as I mentioned in 2, it won't help. Besides, I found that this setting would slow down the speed of training, because peak occupy of GPUs drops from 99% to 90% and the time of not peak become longer by doing so.